# How can I further simplify this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MnZo.jpg the original equation

as for the image provided, is there a way to simplify?
I have reduced the last two portions (the division) down to $$\frac{6}{a+2}$$

So the final equation is the following:
$$\frac{2(a+(a+1)+(a+2)+...+2a)}{a^2+3a+2}+\frac{6}{a+2}$$

Can I reduce it even further? the only thing bothering me is the series part. I don't know what to do with that part.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try it with the gaussian formular summation formular from 0 to 2a and subtract the value of the sum from 0 to a-1 (because $a + ... + 2a = (1 + ... + 2a) - (1 + ... + a-1)$).

Answer (score 1):

Note $a^2+3a+2=(a+2)(a+1)$, so you might expect the term $(a+1)$ to appear in the numerator after simplifications so cancellation occurs.

We have $$a+(a+1)+(a+2)+...+(2a-2)+(2a-1))+2a$$
$$=a+(a+1)+(a+2)+...+(a+(a-2))+(a+(a-1))+a+a$$
$$=\underbrace{a+a+...+a}_{a+1 \space\space\text{times}}+(1+2+3+...+a-1+a)$$
$$=a(\underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{a+1 \space\space\text{times}})+\frac{1}{2}a(a+1)$$
$$=a(a+1)+\frac{1}{2}a(a+1)=\frac{3}{2}a(a+1)$$

---

Or note that the $n$-th term is $b_n=a+n$ so we have $$a+(a+1)+(a+2)+...+(2a-2)+(2a-1))+2a$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{a}b_n=\sum_{n=0}^{a}a+\sum_{n=0}^{a}n$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}a(a+1).$$

---

Or as mentioned by @kerf in the comments $$a+(a+1)+(a+2)+...+(2a-2)+(2a-1))+2a$$
$$=(1+2+3+...+a+...+2a)-(1+2+3+...+(a-2)+(a-1))$$
$$=a(2a+1)-\frac{1}{2}a(a-1)$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}a(a+1)$$

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: sorry, i don't seem to get where the term $\frac{1}{2}a(a+1)$ came from.

Comment: It's the sum of the first $a$ natural numbers. See [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089207/what-must-be-the-simplest-proof-of-the-sum-of-first-n-natural-numbers).